# Can I add other tables in my db?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I add other tables in the database created by django ? It is for my PHP application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking if you can put tables for your PHP application into your django database schema, then yes. Django will simply ignore any tables it doesn't know about. I can't imagine why you wouldn't just create a new schema for the PHP application.

Comment: because my PHP application interact with the django db + new tables :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Just catch [the signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-syncdb) and [do it yourself](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a hosting plan which only has a limited number of databases, but if not, then you really should just create a new database for a new application.

Whilst there is no reason you can't do what you planned, do you want to risk putting all your eggs in one basket?

Comment: my PHP application interact with the django db + new tables. This is why I have to use the existing django db + new tables :)

Comment: Then you can ignore everything I said and carry on as you were :)